# Python checking condition and safety in same if statement

Tags: python, logic, logical-operators

I've been writing some python code where i have a condition if object is None return if its not get object property and check it.Here is an example code:

```
b = None
if b is None or b.property == "something":
    print("yay")
```

when runned code above prints `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'property'` code below prints the same result.

```
b = None
if b.property == "something" or b is None:
    print("yay")
```

Question:
   Asume there is many `or` checks in `if` clause after evaluating one of them true other condisions can be bypassed becouse the result is gonna be true so its waste of `#compute power`.
Same can be applied to `and` operator too if any condition is 0 result is zero.So why the example above fires an `exception`?

Answer (score 1):

I was writing my question than it hit me.Anyway i will leave solution to my problem aswell.

```
if (b is None) or b.property == "something":
    print("yay")
```

`There is a natural order to this world!` =)

Comment: You could also just do "if b or b.property=='something'".

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce the error.

```
>>> b = None
>>> b is None or b.property == 'something'
True
```

However, you may be interested to know that the `or` keyword does not necessarily return `True` or `False`; rather, given the expression `a or b` it returns `a` if `a` is truthy, else it returns `b`, regardless of it's boolean value. We would get the error you described if the order of operations were different:

```
>>> b is (None or b.property) == 'something'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'property'
```